# Rsync inline on large files: is is possible to skip the initial checksums?

Tags: rsync

Trying to sync large files (a VM image) between machines with `rsync single.large.img user@host:/destination/ --inplace --progress` or `rsync *.img user@host:/destination/ --inplace --progress`, the process is reading the entirety of each file at both sides before performing the sync. This seems contrary to the documentation for the `--checksum` option:

> --checksum, -c
> This changes the way rsync checks if the files have been changed and are in need of a transfer. Without this option, rsync uses a "quick check" that (by default) checks if each file's size and time of last modification match between the sender and receiver. This option changes this to compare a 128-bit checksum

As I'm not explicitly specifying `--checksum`, by my reading it should just start syncing without the initial full scans – i.e. read both sides in parallel sending changed blocks over as required, instead of doing *exactly* that after first reading the source then the target which balloons the wall-clock time of the operation considerably.

- I know the files differ, so the initial full checksum shouldn't be needed
- The changes are minimal (relative to filesize) and the connection between hosts isn't terribly speedy, hence trying to sync the changes instead of just copying the whole lot
- The timestamps differ, so the quick check should be sufficient to stop if not syncing at all
- File sizes do not differ (they are older versions of the same statically allocated VM disk images)
- I can't absolutely guarantee room on the target filesystem for a second copy of the file temporarily, hence using `--inline`, I'm aware the dangers of this wrt partial updates if the process is interrupted
- It is syncing rather than copying everything once it starts that part of the process, which I can see by the write-IO pattern at the destination

The process is still much faster than copying the files wholesale, but it could be two-to-three times as quick without needlessly verifying that the files differ with a full checksum.